# Remove default animation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to remove default animation from `Select` label. I have this basic example:

```
export default function TicketProfile(props: any)  {
  return (
    <Container>
      <FormControl sx={{ ml: 1, mr: 1, minWidth: 220 }}>
      <InputLabel id="status-label">Ticket Status</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="status-label"
        id="status-helper"
        name="status"
        label="Select Status"
        options={options}
      >       
      </Select>
      <FormHelperText>Select Ticket Status</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dpj9vp?file=Hello.tsx

As you an see there is a label `Ticket Status` which moves to top when I click on the list. How I can make the text static - always on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `shrink` property on `InputLabel` which you can use.

```
<InputLabel id="status-label" shrink>
  Ticket Status
</InputLabel>
```

[See InputLabel API page](https://mui.com/api/input-label/#main-content)